# 2 kafka consumers to read from 2 different topics with different SSL configuration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am writing a Spring boot app that will consume from 2 different topics and process the message. These 2 topics are hosted on different clusters and have different SSL configurations.
I want to create 2 different consumers to read from the topics.
I am using Spring-cloud-stream and kafka-stream.
Any help on how to setup the application.properties for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @oleg-zhurakousky's answer. If however you want to do this regardless I recommend you look into Spring FactoryBean.

Comment: Is there any sample code that you can help me with?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you described you are creating two independent microservices.

Why merge them into a single application? That kind of defeats the purpose of microservice and the fundamentally goes agains the design and purpose of spring-cloud-stream as a framework. Have you thought about future management, maintenance, support etc? Basically what I mean is that the two consumers are dependent on one another due to resource sharing (memory, CPU etc).

Comment: While it is not clear from the question, the aim may be to compute a join between the inputs of those two topics. There are also many other reasons, why you would want the same application read from two different clusters.

Comment: True, hence let's wait for an answer

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky The app that I am trying to create is basically an aggregator that reads from 2 topics which are in 2 diff clusters and process the messages consumed. We can do the same with Spring-kafka. What I wanted to know was if there is any way do do it using Spring-cloud-stream or Kafka-Stream.

Comment: I don't know much about Spring Cloud Streams. So this comment refers to Kafka Streams only. A topology within Kafka Streams can only read data from one Kafka Cluster. So you would have to replicate the data from one cluster to the other before combining the data with Kafka Streams. This would also bring you close to the micro service approach mentioned by Oleg.